# Creating a Dataframe from data in an existing Dataframe based on bucket'd rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I get that the title is terrible and generic like. I have no idea how to concisely describe what I am trying to do.

I've got a 2 column data frame in R, column A has data values, column B had data that has now been binned (was year associated with Column A, now is a bin label based on year ranges).

I need to generate a new data frame which uses the bin labels as columns with the associated data values as row entries, preferably sorted, back-filled with 'NA' to prevent columns of different lengths.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(values=c(1,NA,3,NA,5:6,7:9),
                 bins=rep(c("yr1_yr2","yr2_yr3","yr3_yr4"),each=3))
```

SOLUTION EDIT: So after a lot of experimentation I was able to do what I wanted with my data by using the 'cut_width' function from ggplot2 to slice my data into bins then plop it in a distribution graph. 
Thank you all for your attempts, sorry again for the vague question and lack of sample data.

Comment: You can use `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(dat), rowid(label) ~ label, value.var = 'year')`

Comment: Perhaps provide your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is getting close to what you want...

`library(tidyverse)
 reshape2::melt(df, id.vars='bins', measure.vars='values')`

returns

```
   bins variable   value
1 yr1_yr2   values     1
2 yr1_yr2   values    NA
3 yr1_yr2   values     3
4 yr2_yr3   values    NA
5 yr2_yr3   values     5
6 yr2_yr3   values     6
7 yr3_yr4   values     7
8 yr3_yr4   values     8
9 yr3_yr4   values     9
```